# Is there a way to close a UIkit toggle on an outside click?

Tags: jquery, uikit, toggle

I'm fiddling around with UIkit's toggle functions and I'm struggling to find a simple way to close the toggle drop when clicking out.

I know that clicking the toggle button will close the drop after it's been opened, however, I also want to add the functionality to close the toggle drop upon click-out/click-away.

Would I have to use a separate jQuery function to sort this or is there an easier way?

I've scanned through the UIkit documentation and it doesn't seem to have functionality for this.

Please see my current code below:

```
<button href="#toggle-animation" class="uk-button uk-button-default" type="button" uk-toggle="target: #toggle-animation; animation: uk-animation-fade">Toggle Button</button>

<div id="toggle-animation" class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-margin-small" hidden>Toggle Drop</div>
```